# How to check if document is existing in Firestore/Firebase and giving it to a var or return it?

Tags: firebase, react-native, return, google-cloud-firestore

I want to render a image when a document in Firestore exists but I don't know how to give the value from a .then function back to its original function and returning true or false is not working.The return value is always true.

```
            renderFollowIcon(email){
                if(
                firebase.firestore().collection("user").doc(this.state.currentUserEmail).collection("follows").doc(email).get()
                .then((docSnapshot) => {
                    if (docSnapshot.exists){
                        Alert.alert("hi")
                        return true;
                    }
                    Alert.alert("not hi")
                    return false;
                })){
                    return(
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.unfollow(email)}>
                            <Image source={require("../assets/unfollow.png")} style={styles.FollowIcon}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                }else{
                    return(
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.follow(email)}>
                            <Image source={require("../assets/follow.png")} style={styles.FollowIcon}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                }
            }
```

Here is the new code but its still not working:

```
                    var promise2 = Promise.resolve().then(firebase.firestore().collection("user").doc(this.state.currentUserEmail).collection("follows").doc(email).get()
                .then((docSnapshot) => {
                    if (docSnapshot.exists){
                        Alert.alert("hi")
                        return Promise.reject( true );
                    }else{
                        Alert.alert("not hi")
                        return Promise.reject( false );
                    }
                    return (check.promise)
                }))
```

@DougStevenson

Answer (score 0):

Your function renderFollowIcon always returns immediately before any of the work is done in Firestore.  That's because the Firestore APIs are asynchronous and return a promise that indicates when the work is finally complete.  You are required to use the promise to find the results of any query.

You can't just return a value from an asynchronous callback.  You should probably instead return a promise to the caller of renderFollowIcon to let them know the results of any async work you do in that function.

Comment: This is my new code: `var promise2 = Promise.resolve().then(firebase.firestore().collection("user").doc(this.state.currentUserEmail).collection("follows").doc(email).get()
        .then((docSnapshot) => {
            var check;
            if (docSnapshot.exists){
                Alert.alert("hi")
                return Promise.reject( true );
            }else{
                Alert.alert("not hi")
                return Promise.reject( false );
            }
            return (check.promise)
        }))`@DougStevenson